# CliffDriving PS

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography, science

[image: CliffDriving PS]

[contextual images]

[text near one image] 16.,51.

Instructions: Name the Town

_ _ s _ _ _ _

Answer (score 2):

Solution Part 1:

> > The grey objects attached to the vertical line are known as Motor Proteins. 
> >  [image]
> > The clue "-T" leads us to think that Motor Protein minus one T is an anagram for something.

Solution Part 2:

> > An anagram for the letters MOORPROTEIN is PROMONTORIES, which is defined as a high point of land jutting out over a large body of water. 
> >  
> >  [image: Promontories]
> >  
> > Noting the vertical surface the motor proteins are attached to, this reinforces that we are on the right track.

Solution Part 3:

> > Without any other clues, we assume a cypher could be the next step. Promontories = 16(P) 18(R) 15(O) 13(M) 15(O) 14(N) 20(T) 15(O) 18(R) 9(I) 5(E) 19(S) = 1618151315142015189519

Solution Part 4:

> > The resulting cypher number shares similarities with the clue "16.,51.", where the number starts with 16, and 51 is right in the middle. When separated to two different numbers, this becomes 16.1815131 and 51.42015189519. Looks like GPS coordinates...

Comment: For part 4, a clue of "16.,.42", would make sense for the answer you give. A clue of "16.,51." would also make sense. But the actual clue is "16.,.51", which doesn't lead to this solution.

Comment: Good catch on the 49 vs 51. It's fixed now. "16.,.51" is correct.

Comment: I think you've missed the problem I was trying to highlight.  51.42015 doesn't match ".51", it matches "51." or ".42". So if this solution is correct, there's an error in the puzzle.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Yes I did mess that one up twice... Ok, I think we are on the right track now.

Comment: I really wish you would add some clues before answering (for example, that there is anagramming involved which is not hinted anywhere).